# ARCH; Expectation and Variance

Tags: homework, garch

I have got the following question that I am struggling to answer.

The stock return $S_t$ follows the following DL model, with $Z_t$ being a dependent variable explaining the stock return:

$S_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 Z_t + \delta \sigma_t + \epsilon_t$

with $\epsilon_t=\sigma_t\zeta_t$ and $\sigma^2_t= \omega + \alpha \epsilon^2_{t-1}$.

Assuming that $\zeta $ is i.i.d. $N(0,1)$, in order to calculate $E[S_t|X_t,\epsilon_{t-1}]$, I set: $\epsilon_t^2 = \sigma_t^2\zeta_t^2 = \zeta_t^2[\omega + \alpha \epsilon^2_{t-1}]$

$E[S_t|X_t,\epsilon_{t-1}] = E[\beta_0 + \beta_1 Z_t + \delta \sigma_t + \epsilon_t|X_t,\epsilon_{t-1}] = E[\beta_0 + \beta_1 Z_t + \delta \sigma_t + \sqrt{\zeta_t^2[\omega + \alpha \epsilon^2_{t-1}]}|X_t,\epsilon_{t-1}]$

Is there an intuition that makes the calculation easier?

Comment: Did you mean $S_t$ and not $R_{t} $. If not, what's $R_{t}$ ?. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, apologies. Question edited!